# Open Directory authenticated bind succeeds, but creates incomplete record

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, opendirectory, directory-services

I have about a dozen Macs running 10.6.7 or 10.6.8, which are all failing to bind properly to my new 10.7.4 Server OD.

I can bind them just fine via Directory Utility or dsconfigldap, and it reports success. However, when I look at the record, it is failing to write the MAC address. Even if I manually update the record with the MAC address, MCX doesn't do anything and clients can't log in to OD accounts.

All of the affected clients have hundreds of lines in the `/Library/Logs/DirectoryService.error.log` like so:

```
2012-09-15 22:23:18 EDT - T[0x00007FFF70292CC0] - GetMACAddress returned 0x  *** bad control string ***  8x
```

I do know that all of these clients were previously managed with the `Guest` computer account, and I also know that they were all imaged with a DeployStudio image when they were purchased.

I've tried `dscacheutil -flushcache`, but after that I'm drawing a blank. Google has a few hits, but nothing very helpful.

Re-imaging would be ideal but probably isn't going to happen.

Anyone come across this before?